# How can I link my C++ program with the newmat class?

Tags: c++

I downloaded newmat package I included the "include.h" and "newmat.h" headers in my program, but it is not recognizing the namespace NEWMAT; if I define the NEWMAT namespace or even delete the whole line I get several errors like:

```
undefined reference to `BaseMatrix::t() const'
```

Seems that there is no link to the library, I searched for solutions on google, some would say I have look for an .o or .a library files from the neewmat package and copy them to the lib folder, and others say that I should link to the library using: gcc myprogram.c thelibrary.o but I didn't find any file with type .o or .a in the newmat package and the dev-C++ compiler didn't recognize the use of gcc as anything special.

I'm a beginner and I would appreciate if someone could help me implement this package on a program.

Comment: What newmat package? Please link to your download page.

Comment: You should elaborate: what is newmat, what's your code, what OS, what compiler, what development env, ...

Comment: I downloaded newmat10 from http://www.robertnz.net/download.html, I'm using windows 8, at first I was working with Dev-C++ 5.11 but I had the problem above, I also went through the steps mentioned on http://www.robertnz.net/VisualC.html with visual studio 2013 but it didn't work, I couldn't create a local workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the [libnewmat10-dev package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libnewmat10-dev) package in Debian / Ubuntu:

```
edd@max:~$ cd /tmp
edd@max:/tmp$ zcat /usr/share/doc/libnewmat10-dev/examples/example.cpp.gz > ex.cpp
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ ex.cpp -o ex -I/usr/include/newmat -lnewmat
edd@max:/tmp$ ./ex | head -25

Demonstration of Matrix package

Print a real number (may help lost memory test): 3.14159


Test 1 - traditional, bad

Estimates and their standard errors

    1.39166     0.53188 
    1.98310     0.20932 
    0.95221     0.27731 


Observations, fitted value, residual value, hat value
    2.400     1.700     8.300     7.770     0.530     0.280 
    1.800     0.900     5.500     5.818    -0.318     0.190 
    2.400     1.600     8.000     7.675     0.325     0.229 
    3.000     1.900     8.500     9.150    -0.650     0.446 
    2.000     0.500     5.700     5.834    -0.134     0.271 
    1.200     0.600     4.400     4.343     0.057     0.480 
    2.000     1.100     6.300     6.405    -0.105     0.143 
    2.700     1.000     7.900     7.698     0.202     0.153 
    3.600     0.500     9.100     9.007     0.093     0.808 
edd@max:/tmp$
```

See the rest of Robert's documentation for more. I used to use newmat quite a bit -- starting well over 20 years ago.  But these days, I much prefer [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) by Conrad Sanderson.

You need to consult the documentation of your idea to see how you alter the linking command, or use a `Makefile`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I'm using windows.
Since you have experience with Armadillo, do you think it would be easier to include and link to my program than newmat10?
I really don't care about what package I have to download I just need it to work